# continuously getting ID's from WCF

Tags: c#, multithreading, wcf, c#-4.0

Hi I am trying to make a thread that continuously runs until the end of the program.  The purpose of this thread is to keep on getting ID's when thee user adds a new pump and passes a pumpID to the WCF, the ID is then added to a combobox.  I have no idea if this is the way to approach it but I have this snippet of code which attempts to implement my problem

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Thread get = new Thread(new ThreadStart(getID));
        get.IsBackground = true;
        get.Start();
    }

    private void getID()
    {
        IDList.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(storeID));
    }

    private void storeID()
    {
        if (!IDList.Items.Contains(WCFPOS.getIDs()))
        {
            IDList.Items.Add(WCFPOS.getIDs());
        }
    }
```

however it only returns 0 however many pumps I start up.

Answer (score 0):

Your seems does not pass nothing to WCF.

You need to update wcf IDs list before you getting ids from it.

Also, do you realize, that you are executing method **WCFPOS.getIDs()** twice!?

```
if (!IDList.Items.Contains(WCFPOS.getIDs()))
        {
            IDList.Items.Add(WCFPOS.getIDs());
        }
```

At least you can change your code to do it once, like

```
var idList = WCFPOS.getIDs();

if(idList.Any() && 
   !IDList.Items.Contains(idList /*this logic also invalid, thins you are searching for list in the list */)
{
    //Are you adding single or multiple ids?
     IDList.Items.Add(WCFPOS.getIDs());
}
```